# How to know whether a vertex exists in my graph?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

I'm making a method that load a graph from a file. It's very simple, but if there are repeated vertex, the method'll insert too into the graph, so I'm trying to avoid this.

This is my current code:

```
public static Graph<ElementoDecorado<Integer>, String> loadGraphFromFile(File f) {
        boolean v1_exists = false, v2_exists = false;
        Graph<ElementoDecorado<Integer>, String> g = new AdjacencyListGraph<ElementoDecorado<Integer>, String>();
        Vertex<ElementoDecorado<Integer>> v1, v2, aux = null;
        Scanner fr;

        try {
            fr = new Scanner(f);

            while(fr.hasNextLine()) {
                v1 = g.insertVertex(new ElementoDecorado<Integer>(fr.nextInt()));
                v2 = g.insertVertex(new ElementoDecorado<Integer>(fr.nextInt()));

                for(Vertex<ElementoDecorado<Integer>> v : g.vertices()) {
                    if(v.equals(v1)) {

                        /*aux = v;
                        v1_exists = true;*/
                    }
                    if(v.equals(v2)) {
                        /*aux = v;
                        v2_exists = true;*/
                    }
                }

                g.insertEdge(v1, v2, "edge");

                v1_exists = v2_exists = false;
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return g;
    }
```

I don't know what to write into the two ifs. I have tried to delete the vertex if they are equal but obviously this doesn't work cause at the end my graph'll be empty :S

[This is the manual page](http://net3.datastructures.net/doc5/net/datastructures/Vertex.html) for the Vertex interface.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks, and merry christmas!

Comment: The documentation is very poor, but it is `graph.insertEdge(v1, v2, o)` that should add the vertices if necessary.  The doc says nothing about what is actually going on.

Comment: I guess the Graph can have many Vertex's with the same Integer.  But you want to restrict that to a single Vertex for each Integer.

Comment: That's probably the first thing to check, find out if that's what it does.

Comment: @Francis Actually, I don't think it would work even if `insertEdge` did add the vertices since v1 and v2 would be new vertices, even if their Integer value is the same as some existing vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check what `graph.insertVertex(V value)` does.  If the package was build decently (which I doubt from the poor documentation), then that method will only create a new vertex if a vertex with `value` does not already exist; otherwise it returns the existing vertex of value `value`.

However I can't tell from the non-documentation whether the package really assumes that there is a single vertex for a given value and whether `insertVertex` behaves correctly.

Here is some code in case `insertVertex` does not check for duplication:

(I replaced `ElementoDecorado<Integer>` by `Integer` for readability)

```
while(fr.hasNextLine()) {
   int nodeId1 = fr.nextInt();
   int nodeId2 = fr.nextInt();
   Vertex<Integer> vert1 = null;
   Vertex<Integer> vert2 = null;

   for(Vertex<Integer> v : g.vertices()) {
      int nodeId = v.element();
      if(nodeId == nodeId1) 
         vert1 = v;
      else if (nodeId == nodeId2) // assumes can't have nodeId1 == nodeId2
         vert2 = v;
    }
    if (vert1 == null)
       vert1 = g.insertVertex(nodeId1);
    if (vert2 == null)
       vert2 = g.insertVertex(nodeId2);

    g.insertEdge(vert1, vert2, null);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you insert the vertex in the graph, ask if there is a already a `String` value for the given vertex key.

```
vertex = new ElementoDecorado<Integer>(fr.nextInt());
if(graph.get(key) != null) { 
    //it exists, don't insert it
} else { 
    g.insertVertex(vertex)
}
```

Know your own data structures.  Ask yourself, what is the graph made of?  It's just a mapping of :

```
ElementoDecorado<Integer> => String
```

Also do not name your variables things like: `g`.  It doesn't convey any meaning.

Comment: I can't see a `get` method in `Graph`, am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like it's a map, but you're right Francis, I think I may have jumped the gun.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding the vertices to the graph *BEFORE* you check if you need to add them.
First, instead of directly adding both vertices, just read them:

```
v1 = new ElementoDecorado<Integer>( fr.nextInt() );
v2 = new ElementoDecorado<Integer>( fr.nextInt() );
```

Then, in the `for`, you check whether the vertex exists, just like you were trying. Your `if`s could look like this:

```
if( !v1_exists && v.equals( v1 ) ) {
    v1 = v;
    v1_exists = true;
}
```

And similarly for `v2`. At the end, if and only if `v1_exists` is false, you add the vertex:

```
// right anfter the for-each
if ( !v1_exists ) {
    g.addVertex( v1 );
}
if ( !v1_exists ) {
    g.addVertex( v2 );
}

g.insertEdge( v1, v2, "edge" );
// etc
```

There are a few optimizations you could also do, such as stopping the `for` when both vertices are found, but that should do it.

Note that it might be a better way of doing it, but I don't know those classes.